# kotlin add method, having difficulty understanding the "it" argument

Tags: android, kotlin

```
private fun defaultOptions() {
   val options = ArrayList<TextView>() 
   tvoptionone?.let { options.add(0, it) } 
}
```

I am currently using the `add(index, element)` method in kotlin, However, I don't seem to understand what it represents in the element parameter of the add method.

These are the parameters for the add method I am trying to use

```
add(index, element)
```

Answer (score 1):

`it` is the `context object` on which you've used the `let` function.

As you've used it with `safe call operator` (`?.`) it would only call `let` if object is `non null`.

Using `?.let` ensures the `lambda` to be executed only when the `object` is non null. `?.` ensures that object has to be `non null` and `let` makes that object available as `it` inside the lamda.

Here

```
tvoptionone?.let { options.add(0, it) }
```

`it` is a `TextView` as `tvoptionone` is a `TextView`, and `it` has a value same as `tvoptionone`.

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, however from what I understand instances and objects are terms used interchangeably. I also understand that context allows your view to call and get information about other parts of your program ie (environment data).
I am having difficulty understanding what context objects mean, what does context object mean?

Comment: `context object` is the very object we are calling these functions on. Here `tvoptionone?.let` `let` is used on the `tvoptionsone`, so `tvoptionone` is `context object` here. Give this a read, you'll be able to understand it in detail https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#context-object-this-or-it

Answer (score 0):

In the below code

```
tvoptionone?.let { options.add(0, it) } }
```

it refers to tvoptionone 
notice that lambda passed to let will be called only when tvoptionone is not null, so here it refers to tvoptionone and its value is not null

Answer (score 0):

Questionmark after variable `tvoptionone` indicates that this variable can be `null`. If you write just:

`options.add(0, tvoptionone)`

and variable happens to be `null` then the `add` method will throw an error with wording like *param element cannot be null* or so.

Keyword `let`, in this particular example, is kind of a guardian against passing `null` into `add` method. If `tvoptionone` has some value (is not `null`) then `it` will be `tvoptionone` itself. Otherwise `add` method will not be called at all and compilation error will be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Scope functions are the ones you run on a value, and provide a function to run using that value. There's two kinds of scope functions in Kotlin - the ones where the value is passed in as a `parameter` (`let, also` etc.) and the ones where it becomes `this` (`run, apply` etc). They work the same, it just changes how you interact with the value - sometimes one is more convenient or suitable than the other

`it` is just the default name for the parameter passed in:

```
// these two are the same thing
name.let { println("Hi $it") }
name.let { it -> println("Hi $it") }
// rename it to something that reads better if you like
personData.firstName.let { name -> println("Hi $name") }
```

People have mentioned the null-check feature, where you can make the `let` block only run if the value is non-null:

```
name?.let { println("Hi $it, looking very not-null today") }
```

but another use for it is creating a temporary variable. If you have a `var`, it's possible the value will change while you're using it, so it's common to take a copy of it (so you know your copy won't change):

```
var importantNumber = 123
if (importantNumber > 100) {
    // but it might have just been changed by another thread / coroutine and be < 100!
    doThing(importantNumber)
}
```

```
var importantNumber = 123
val copy = importantNumber
if (copy > 100) {
    // the copy can't change, so we know once we've checked it, it's fine
    doThing(copy)
}
```

since `let` creates a variable to pass in as a parameter, it's basically making a copy in the same way:

```
var importantNumber = 123
importantNumber.let { if (it > 100) doThing(it) } // safe because 'it' won't change
```

and that's super important for nullable `var`s - if you check they're null, you need to know they'll stay null. Using `?.let` guarantees that the value passed in as `it` will be non-null, because it's a copy that's been null-checked